# SearchView with multiple fragments using viewpager in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

I want to implement SearchView with multiple fragments present in a viewPager. All fragemnts contains lists and I want to filter those lists and create a new ListView which has categorization of results based upon which fragment it belongs to.

But my searchView is not working with one fragment.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.codeon.directory;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.FiveFragment;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.FourFragment;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.OneFragment;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.SixFragment;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import com.codeon.directory.fragments.TwoFragment;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nikhil Jain on 21-Sep-15.
 */
public class TabEffect extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    public String pic[] = {"1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"};
    public String state[] = {"A","B","C"};
    public String city[] = {"P","Q","R"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablayout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.tab, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArray("pic", pic);
        bundle.putStringArray("district", city);
        bundle.putStringArray("state", state);
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE FRAGMENT", bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO FRAGMENT", bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE FRAGMENT", bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "FOUR FRAGMENT", bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE FRAGMENT", bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new SixFragment(), "SIX FRAGMENT", bundle);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, Bundle args) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first fragment :

```
package com.codeon.directory.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.codeon.directory.R;
import com.codeon.directory.RecyclerAdapter;
import com.codeon.directory.customadapters.Listitems_new;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nikhil Jain on 21-Sep-15.
 */
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView rootView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Bundle extras = getArguments();
        String pic[] = extras.getStringArray("pic");
        String state[] = extras.getStringArray("state");
        Log.e("VALUE",pic[0]+pic[1]+pic[2]);

        rootView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext()));
        //listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, pic);
        rootView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(pic));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My SearchActivity:

```
package com.codeon.directory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
  * Created by Nikhil Jain on 21-Sep-15.
*/
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
        Log.e("QUERY", query);
    }
}

private void doMySearch(String query) {

}
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TabEffect"
        android:label="@string/tablayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@layout/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

This is my Searchable layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

For simple, I want to implement searchView like in Whatsapp.

[image]

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Good structuring with the question. Any solutions yet ?!

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

@Chintan is right. We need to use ViewModel.
Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).

1. Create SearchViewModel:

'''

```
private MutableLiveData<String> query= new MutableLiveData<String>();

public void setQuery(String queryData)
{
    query.setValue(queryData);
}

public LiveData<String> getQuery() {
    return query;
}
```

'''

2. SearchParentFragment

'''

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    final MenuItem myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_icon);

    searchViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SearchViewModel.class);

    searchView = (SearchView) myMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            searchViewModel.setQuery(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

'''

3. For each Child Fragment (tabs)

'''

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    searchViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SearchViewModel.class);
    searchViewModel.getQuery().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            if (s!=null)
            {adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });
}
```

'''

A single query will work for all tabs.)
I studied it for a long time, but this solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got my fragments have list with one Searchview working by using following code..
Place the code in each fragment where you want to

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser)
    {
       search_bar.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        if(listAdapter!=null)
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(search_bar.getQuery());
    }
}
```

Screenshots: 
[image: Chats tab is active]
[image: Contacts tab is active]

Comment: need full code link

Answer (score 1):

Below hint may help you

`public class AnyActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
 private ListenFromActivity activityListener1;
}`

then define interface with separate file

`public interface ListenFromActivity {
    void doSearchInFragment(String SearchKey);
}`

now in your fragment

```
    public class Connections extends Fragment implements ListenFromActivity 
    { 
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      ((AnyActivity)Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setActivityTab1Listener(Connections.this);

    }
    @Override
    public void doSearchInFragment(String SearchKey) {
    //pass to any network or local call.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You wanna search your query to all fragment must use **Viewmodel** with **Livedata**.
Set Your Query in **Livedata** then Your **Livedata** Observe on all Your Fragment.

This Code in viewPager side

```
val searchLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
searchLiveData.postValue("query")
```

This code in all Fragments

```
mainViewModel.searchLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { query ->
     //Add your code
})

//1
val liveData: MutableLiveData<Any>()
//2
liveData.value = "Hello"
//3
liveData.observe(this, Observer { 
  // Update UI  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer Любовь,realy help me.ViewModel fits well with fragments.
So if you want to trigger search from MainActivity.
You need to create:
1.ViewModel

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {
public   MutableLiveData<String> query = new MutableLiveData<String>();
public void setQuery(String queryData) {

    query.setValue(queryData);
}
public LiveData<String> getQuery() {

    return query;
}
```

2.Create instance of it in activity where you want trigger and perform search.

```
searchViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) bottomAppBar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
                    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                            Log.i("onQueryTextSubmit", query);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                            searchViewModel.setQuery(newText);
                            Log.i("onQueryTextChange", newText);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

3.Create instance of ViewModel in fragments to observe changes of it in mainActivity(in this way u pass data from activity to fragment)

```
searchViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(SearchViewModel.class);
    searchViewModel.getQuery().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
                Log.i("onChanged",s);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                Log.i("filter",s);
            }
        }
    });
```

4.Override and implement custom getFilter in your adapter (only if u supply custom object to it) if its array of strings,getFilter now how to work with it.

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new SearchFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
```

private class SearchFilter extends Filter
{

```
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence s) {

        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if(s != null && s.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            s = s.toString().toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<Word> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Word>();

            for(int i = 0, l = searchList.size(); i < l; i++)
            {
                if(searchList.get(i).getmDefaultTranslation().toLowerCase().contains(s))
                {
                    Word x = new Word(searchList.get(i).getmDefaultTranslation(),searchList.get(i).getmMiwokTranslation(),
                            searchList.get(i).getmImageResourceId(),searchList.get(i).getmAudioResourceId());
                    filteredItems.add(x);
                   
                }
            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        }else {
            result.count = searchList.size();
            result.values = searchList;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence s,
                                  FilterResults results) {

        numbersWords = (ArrayList<Word>)results.values;
        Log.i("new search", String.valueOf(results));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Sorry for my technical language!!!
And here is the link for my repo where u can check full implementation of search with multiple fragments(using ViewModel)
https://github.com/artnkfv/Multiscreen_App/tree/main_v1.1