# android tab view fragment Recycler view search filter

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, android-filterable, android-filter

I want to implement search filter in Tab view Fragment with data from sqlite database ,after more that three days of being though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763745/searchview-with-multiple-fragments-using-viewpager-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516621/searchview-doesnt-filter-in-each-child-tab-of-tablayout)  without success finally  i came across [this](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/Android-Filter-RecyclerView-Using-SearchView-In-ToolBar.html) which is seems to be clean idea since am kind new to android development.
 i tried to implement it but does not seems to work it means  search menu item not inflating also i  get no result, i do not  have idea where do i get t wrong and there is no error at all, any idea on what is wrong and how to make it work.

here is the Fragment code

```
public class TabFragment3 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private UsersAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  arrayList;
DBController controller = new DBController(getContext());
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_3, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    controller = new DBController(getContext());
    arrayList = controller.getAllUsers();
    adapter = new UsersAdapter(arrayList,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
      }

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
             arrayList = controller.getAllUsers();
           // Do something when collapsed
            adapter.setFilter(arrayList);
            return true; // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
           // Do something when expanded
            return true; // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
 // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userlist = controller.getAllUsers();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> entry : userlist){
        String name2= entry.get("number").toLowerCase();
        if(name2.contains(newText)){
            newList.add(entry);
        }}
    adapter.setFilter(newList);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
 ///  adapter class

 public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSet= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();
Context ctx;
public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSet,Context ctx) {
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    this.ctx=ctx;
}
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_row, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(v,mDataSet,ctx);
    return userViewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).get("userId"));
    holder.email_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).get("userName"));
    holder.icon_entry.setText(""+mDataSet.get(position).get("number"));
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView name_entry, email_entry, icon_entry;
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSet= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();
    public UserViewHolder(View itemView, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSet,Context ctx) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mDataSet=mDataSet;
        this.ctx= ctx;
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_layout);
        name_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
        email_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_entry);
        icon_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_entry);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public void setFilter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newList){
    mDataSet= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    mDataSet.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

/// main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener  {
private ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
{ return false;
 }
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

  return false;
        }
```

}

Comment: what issue are you facing? is search menu item not inflating? or you are not getting the result? Or what is it?

Comment: it does not inflating therefore even there result is not found@Sherl0cked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your TabFragment3's `onCreateView()` method.  It tells the host activity that your fragment has menu options that it wants to add.
2. Also add `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater)`..

   `@Override
       public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
       }`
3. Inside the MainActivity's `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` **return false**, as the Menu item action would be hanlded in TabFragment3's `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

Comment: i tried the concept but still does not work  @Sherl0cked

Comment: solved nothing? still can't see the search icon in the toolbar?

Comment: search i con is there but it does not inflating @Sherl0cked

Comment: finally i got made it with you codes  thanks a lot @Sherl0cked

Comment: i Getting wrong item selected from filtered list using recyclerview @Sherl0cked can youhelp?